# JavaFX disable Maximize button from StageStyle.Utility

Tags: java, javafx

I am initializing my stage with `StageStyle.Utility`. This is how the buttons look like:

[image]

One is the close button, which is fine. Minimize is disable, which is great. But... Maximize is there. I don't want my utility window to be able to maximize.

I have disabled Resizing, but at least on Mac it is still able to maximize. How do I disable this? (I DO want to have `StageStyle.Utility`).

**Edit:** This is how it looks when I hover the mouse on either of them:

[image]

It is an 'X', but it does NOT close the window! It maximizes it!

Comment: Is that a Mac "feature"? In Win7 there's only a close button. WindowStage.initPlatformWindow has: case UTILITY: windowMask |=  Window.TITLED | Window.UTILITY | Window.CLOSABLE; i. e. no Minimizable, Maximizable.

Comment: @Roland Yes, this is specific to Mac. For more information, you can go through [this ticket](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36083).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
stage.setResizable(false);
```

along with

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

It disables both maximize and minimize options.

[image]

Comment: This is so strange. I'm already doing this and it doesn't work. However, from what I can see, are you using an older version of OSX? I am using Yosemite and the maximize button is just like in my image (it's a red button, but if you press it, it actually maximizes the window regardless of `setResizable` and `StageStyle.UTILITY`).

Comment: In fact, this is how the buttons look when you hover the mouse over either of them: http://i.stack.imgur.com/81fZO.png (but the third button does NOT close the window - it maximizes it!)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? There was a bug reported for Yosemite for incorrect window decoration while using `StageStyle.UTILITY`.